# Scrapy - 400 Response with Headers

Tags: python, scrapy

Here's an example link I'm trying to scrape: https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-7-Burners-4-cu-ft-2-cu-ft-Double-Oven-Convection-Dual-Fuel-Range-Stainless-Steel-Common-48-in-Actual-48-in/1000514227

My scraper was working fine till today so I'm guessing Lowe's added more protection against bots :(

After some research, I found that I would have to add headers to my web scraper so I can emulate a real user.

Opened up Dev Console -> Network -> XHR/Fetch -> Found JSON File.

Here's my scrapy script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import LowesItem
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from scrapy.http import Request
from datetime import date


class LowesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Lowes'

   

 



    def start_requests(self):


        HEADERS = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'scheme': 'https',
            'authority': 'content.syndigo.com',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'Origin': 'https://lowes.com',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Host': 'content.syndigo.com',
            'User-Agent': ' Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15',
            'Referer': 'https://www.lowes.com/',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cookie': 'sn=0321'

        }


        

        start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-7-Burners-4-cu-ft-2-cu-ft-Double-Oven-Convection-Dual-Fuel-Range-Stainless-Steel-Common-48-in-Actual-48-in/1000514227']

        for url in start_urls:
            yield Request(url,
                        headers=HEADERS,
                        meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True,
                          'url':url}) 

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in self.parseLowes(response):
            yield item
        pass

    def parseLowes(self, response):
        item = LowesItem() #items from items.py
        

        script_tag = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').get() #get js container
        productPrice = json.loads(script_tag)[2]["offers"]["price"]

        productURL = response.url
        url = response.meta['url']
        productSKU = url.split("=")[-1]

        scrapedDate = date.today()

        #item['productName'] = productName #display product name
        item['productOMS'] = productSKU
        item['productPrice'] = productPrice #display price and assign to variable
        item['productURL'] = productURL #displayURL
        item['scrapedDate'] = scrapedDate
        yield item
```

[image]

When I run scrapy, I get 400 as a response from the command.

Comment: I have tried accessing the link in a normal browser and I still get Access denied. Do you need to be logged in to access the individual product pages?

Comment: @msenior_ that’s interesting, did you open a private window or have your location off? the reason i have cookie = 0321 is because i think the site bases prices based on region

Comment: I think the "path" in the header of the request is encrypted by something. I know that some websites are using this method to prevent scrapers access their data.

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati so to scrape this site, I would have to use a headless browser I'm guessing

Comment: I'm not sure about this. But that could be a way at least to try.

Comment: lowes.com is a difficult-to-scrape website. You'd need a proxy rotation service to deal with its banning such as - https://www.zyte.com/smart-proxy-manager/

Comment: Have the same problem, cannot access any items from my chrome :o

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see about the network connection, the issue is related to the  their CDN (Akamai) which is blocking the access.

I was able to access your link and see the product from Microsoft Edge (version 107). In my request the user agent is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/107.0.1418.26
```

So, try to modify in your code the 'User-Agent' key with that value.